# Is it ok to have 3 views?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, oop

I have a model which returns to controller arrays of user's information (his posts, information(name,age etc.) and etc). Then I have one view file which has lots of html (tables and etc.) and it represents the user. I need to show the exactly the same user's profile somewhere else too. Problem is, that before user profile I need to add a few divs. So, is it ok to do like this in one controller:

```
$this->loadView("HeaderOfParticularPage"); //it contains just divs
$this->loadView("UserProfile", $user); //$user is array of arrays of information of user
$this->loadView("SomeOtherInfoINeedForFooter");
```

Is it ok? Or it's bad practise? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's perfectly acceptable to modularize and reuse views like that, since each serves a different purpose of its own. MVC web apps aren't restricted to a single view (or a single controller, or a single model) per page.

You could even say that what you're doing is the "MVC version" of server-side includes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is fine.

If anything it is considered good practice to split your views up like you have. This allows for a far more modular approach allowing you to reuse view elements over and over again within the different pages of your website or web application.